# How to loop through a variable contain String?

Tags: php

I have a variable in which I have stored some string. I want to remove a specific string from that particular variable by looping in the variable. I have an example below for the variable and I wish to remove the string `"name"`. How should I proceed?

```
$temp="";
$temp.="John";
$temp.="has";
$temp.="name";
```

Comment: If it's always going to be just the same word, you could use `str_replace()`? `$temp = str_replace('name', '', $temp);`

Comment: Why have you tagged this `javascript`?

Comment: This is PHP, what does it have to do with Javascript ?

Comment: Everyone started new and hes obv. a newbie, stop punishing ppl for doing a mistake ...

Comment: the str_replace() didn't work

Comment: can you show us the relevant part of the code?

Comment: i made a mistake in using the str_replace(); but now its ok i got what i wanted :)Thnx for the help

Comment: Can you please tell me how to loop through the variable using a for loop to get all the String in the $temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no sense in that, but try this:

```
$temp = str_replace("name", "", $temp);
```

Comment: You probably forgot to save the value the function returned. Look at the edited code

Comment: i made a mistake in using the str_replace(); but now its ok i got what i wanted :)Thnx for the help

Can you please tell me how to loop through the variable using a for loop to get all the String in the $temp

Comment: What do you mean with all the Strings in Temp? When you put the Strings together, its one string, php cant know that these were single strings. You can put a whitespace behind each string and then use explode() to seperate the string at each whitespace. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Will this suffice ?

```
<?php
echo str_replace("name","",$temp);
```

Comment: i made a mistake in using the str_replace(); but now its ok i got what i wanted :)Thnx for the help